# Values are not displaying in UserInterface using Web Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jscript

I am new in Selenium webdriver.When i reading values from Excel sheet and saved to database.The values are not displaying in the webpage and also not inserted to Database. 
Here this is my code for one form.If there any way for solving this issue.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class DeliveryNote 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException
      {


         //For ChromeBrowser
         //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/Softwares/Chrome/Chromedriver.exe");
         //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Puts a Implicit wait, Will wait for 10 seconds before throwing exception
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Launch website
        driver.navigate().to("http://192.168.1.185:8080/Nayonika/loginPage.html");
        //Maximize the browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize();


        // xpath of username
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[1]/input")).sendKeys("aaa");

        // xpath of password
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[2]/input")).sendKeys("2222");

        //xpath of checkbox
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[3]/label/input")).click();

        //xpath of login button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[4]/input")).click();

     System.out.println(" Login Successfully.....");


     //Puts a Implicit wait, Will wait for 20 seconds before throwing exception
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     //Navigate to sales
     Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
     //Xpath of Documents
     WebElement Mainmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/ul/li[1]/a"));
     //xpath of Sales
     WebElement Submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));
     //xpath of Delivery Note
     WebElement Childsubmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[5]/a"));
     actions.moveToElement(Mainmenu).moveToElement(Submenu).moveToElement(Childsubmenu).click().build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(5000);

     //Specify the file path of the excelsheet
      FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("D:\\7SYSERP\\deliverynote.xls");
        Workbook W = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
        //TO get the access to the sheet
        Sheet s = W.getSheet(0);



 // xpath of New Button
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[2]/tr[2]/td/input[1]")).click(); 

  for(int i = 4; i<= 5;i++)  
       {


             // xpath of New Button
             //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[2]/tr[2]/td/input[1 ")).click(); 
             //Puts a Implicit wait, Will wait for 10 seconds before throwing exception 
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //xpath of  StockDetail id
            String stkdtlid = s.getCell(0,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("StockDetail id" + stkdtlid);
            // driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys(stkdtlid); 
           //driver.findElement(By.id("1196")).clear(); 
           driver.findElement(By.id("1196")).sendKeys(stkdtlid);
           System.out.println("StockDetail id1" + stkdtlid);
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //xpath of Delivery Note Detail Remarks
            String remarks = s.getCell(1,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("Delivery Note Detail Remarks" +remarks);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(remarks);
            //driver.findElement(By.id("287")).clear(); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("287")).sendKeys(remarks);
            System.out.println("Delivery Note Detail Remarks 1" +remarks);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // xpath of Delivery Note Details Status id
            String delntdtlstatusid = s.getCell(2,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("Delivery Note Details Status id" +delntdtlstatusid);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[3]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(delntdtlstatusid);       
            //driver.findElement(By.id("286")).clear(); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("286")).sendKeys(delntdtlstatusid);
            System.out.println("Delivery Note Details Status id 1" +delntdtlstatusid);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //xpath of  Quantity
            String qty = s.getCell(3,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("Quantity " +qty );
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[4]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[4]/input")).sendKeys(qty ); 
            //driver.findElement(By.id("285")).clear(); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("285")).sendKeys(qty);
            System.out.println("Quantity 1" +qty );
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //xpath of Unit id
            String untitid = s.getCell(4,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("Unit id" +untitid);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[5]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[5]/input")).sendKeys(untitid);    
            //driver.findElement(By.id("284")).clear(); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("284")).sendKeys(untitid); 
            System.out.println("Unit id 1" +untitid);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //xpath of Item id 
            String itemid = s.getCell(5,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("Item id " + itemid);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[6]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[6]/input")).sendKeys(itemid);
            //driver.findElement(By.id("283")).clear(); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("283")).sendKeys(itemid);
            System.out.println("Item id 1 " + itemid);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // xpath of Delivery Note id
            String delvrynteid = s.getCell(6,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("Delivery Note id" +delvrynteid);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[7]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[7]/input")).sendKeys(delvrynteid);
            //driver.findElement(By.id("282")).clear(); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("282")).sendKeys(delvrynteid);
            System.out.println("Delivery Note id 1" +delvrynteid);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

             // xpath of Delivery Note Detail id
            String delvryntedtlid = s.getCell(7,i).getContents();
            System.out.println("Delivery Note Detail id " +delvryntedtlid);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[8]/input")).clear(); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[8]/input")).sendKeys(delvryntedtlid);
            //driver.findElement(By.id("281")).clear(); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("281")).sendKeys(delvryntedtlid);
            System.out.println("Delivery Note Detail id 1 " +delvryntedtlid);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


         // xpath of Save   
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[9]/input[1]")).click(); 
            System.out.println("Saved");
      }


    driver.close();

  }

}
```

Comment: Your issue is - you are reading data from excel, enter in a webpage and submit it. Now the data is not saved in database? Is my understanding correct?  If yes, Does it work fine when you do it manually? If no, Please provide more details.

Comment: Yes.When entering the values in manually it work properly.

Comment: When you run the scripts, does it read the spreadsheet and enter the values ? Is it not clicking on the save button properly?

Comment: Yes.it also read the spreadsheet values.Also written the save button code.But when i executing the script it is not working properly.